# Android wear app goes black screen when I tap anything

Tags: android, wear-os

I made my first hello world app, launched it on my smart watch (Gear Live), and it looks fine.

But then, as soon as my finger touches the screen, my watch turns into a pure black screen, and my hello world app is gone. There is nothing in Logcat, not a single word.

Is there a debug setting on this or something that I overlooked?

EDIT: Did more tests, out of 20 times I launched this app from Android Studio, all 20 of them showed "Hello World" on my watch, and 17 of them crashed when I tap anything. 3 of them did not crash when I tap, and they do not crash no matter what I do (until I swipe from left, which closes it).

Comment: Did you add any Flag/WakeLock to your Activity?

Comment: Nope. There is nothing in this app, just a hello world.